# Moving focus to next tab group in Visual Studio 2008/Visual Studio 2010 via the keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to move to the next vertical tab group in Visual Studio 2008 or 2010 by using the keyboard?

There are commands for moving the active window to the next or previous tab group, but I couldn't find one for moving the focus from one tab group to the next.

The only workaround that I found is by using DPack's File Browser dialog, but it requires a lot of keystrokes and they depend on the name of file in the currently active windows in the tab groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [VSStreamliner](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6e2772e9-18e4-4409-8de4-8afec9e0603a) extension adds keybindings for this exact functionality.  It's working great for me in VS2010.

Comment: I hacked VSStreamliner to work with VS2015 by using the same method described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14087731/1783777), setting version number to 14.0.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Visual Studio 2012, [TabGroupJumper](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3e255015-41c3-47db-b25b-45e00c107875?SRC=VSIDE) provides commands to move to the next/previous tab group in any direction.

Comment: Just commenting to say that it has been updated to work with VS 2013 (and hopefully all coming MSVC versions). Although this does require compiling it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

It should be <kbd>F6</kbd>, but it doesn't work for me.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> cycles through all open documents, but that isn't exactly what you want.

Comment: F6 is moving the cursor between split parts of an editor window.