# Visual Studio 2012 Emacs key bindings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, emacs

Could someone describe the instructions to setup emacs key bindings in Visual Studio 2012 environment? I saw a couple of thread, but they didn't really cut it for me.

It'd be great to have someone using it post instructions about it.

Related Thread:
[Emacs Keybindings in Visual Studio 2012 or 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884953/emacs-keybindings-in-visual-studio-2012)

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: Did you see the answer on that question? Did you try it? What problems did you face?

Comment: it doesn't work. I got an error stating this visual studio extension cannot be installed on any products. I've cloned the line for VS 10 and changed it from 10 to 11.                                                  <VisualStudio Version="10.0">
        <Edition>Pro</Edition>
      </VisualStudio>
     <VisualStudio Version="11.0">
        <Edition>Pro</Edition>  
      </VisualStudio>