# Installing Emacs Emulation keybindings -- Invalid VSIX package

Tags: visual-studio-2012, key-bindings, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm trying to install the extension for Visual Studio 2012 that allows emacs key-bindings.

I'm following through the steps here:

[Emacs Keybindings in Visual Studio 2012 or 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884953/emacs-keybindings-in-visual-studio-2012)

I'm up to step 5:

> Run the vsik file as administrator. This is required so the extension
>   can write Emacs.vsk into the program files folder. I wasn't sure the
>   best way to do this so I ran a command prompt as admin and then
>   executed start emacsemulations.vsik from the prompt.

So, running emacsemulations.vsix from an administrator command prompt,
I get the following error "This VSIX package is invalid because it does not contain the file extension.vsixmanifest at the root."

I'm not changing any of the file names inside the package.

I'm thinking this may have something to do with how windows zips up the file -- I'm able to recreate the problem simply by unzipping and rezipping the EmacsEmulation.vsix file without changing the contents of the vsix package.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix, or even better, the actual updated vsix file itself, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have relies on the way you are zipping your file, what you should do is zip all files inside the folder you created (in this case, "EmacsEmulations") when you unzipped it.

1. Step into the EmacsEmulations folder.
2. Select all files.
3. Add to .zip
4. Rename the .zip output to EmacsEmulations.vsix

I'm trying to get this extension to work too, so good luck!