# Visual Studio 2015 builtin Emacs keybindings won't work?

Tags: visual-studio, key-bindings

I'm trying to make use of Visual Studio's Emacs keybindings. In particular `EmacsWordNext`, I tried first mapping to `Ctrl-Right`, hit `Assign` and `OK` it didn't work, hitting `Ctrl-Right` doesn't do anything. I thought maybe because of the key conflict so I tried a different combo, one that didn't conflict, but same. I tried other Emacs binding but none did anything. I thought it was my Visual Studio on my machine, so I tried it on another machine but same thing...

Using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

HI this links below discuss similar issues you can try the solution there .

[Using Emacs bindings in Visual Studio Community 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618036/using-emacs-bindings-in-visual-studio-community-2015)

Comment: Yeah I tried that. I got the shortcuts to map and work. But they didn't have the effect I had in mind. I thought that `EmacsWordNext` would go to the next identifier/word _within_ a word. e.g. `|PropertyInfo` -> WordNext -> `Property|Info` (| is the caret position) but it wasn't the case, it acted like a normal `Edit.WordNext` which skips the entire word. Am I missing something?